# Custom Application not created on Android M (final preview)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

The documentation of [`Application#onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) states:

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.

This has been true in practise for as long as I can remember and a lot of applications rely on this for initializing various stuff. However, this behavior has seemingly changed with the latest Android M preview (released yesterday).

When the application is first installed and launched, the custom `Application`'s `onCreate()` won't be called. Instead, it'll launch the first `Activity` immediately.

This only happens on the very first application start. All following application starts work and behave as expected and the custom `Application`'s `onCreate()` is called before starting the `Activity`.

---

### Code example

**BaseApplication**

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      Log.d("App", "Test: Application.onCreate()");
   }
}
```

**FirstActivity**

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Log.d("App", "Test: Activity.onCreate()");
   }
}
```

**App manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.package.name" >

   <application android:name=".application.BaseApplication" >
   [...]
   </application>
</manifest>
```

---

### Logcat output

The screenshot below shows the Logcat output after launching the app from a clean install, and then launching it again 8 seconds after.

[image: Logcat output]

Comment: Bug added to official issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2965

Comment: Just tried on emulator with latest version and it works as expected

Comment: Would you mind posting your code? I'm not unfamiliar with Android development, and I really don't see why my code shouldn't work, but it doesn't work on my Nexus 6 running the latest preview. It worked on both previous previews.

Comment: There isn't anything special, I added logs like you. I'm wondering if the problem is about nexus 6. Have you tried the same app on the emulator?

Comment: Try using allowBackup="true" in your manifest. Seems like that has something to do with it.

Comment: I've done my test with allowBackup="true"

Comment: Might very well be a device specific issue then. The issue disappears when I use allowBackup="false".

Comment: I didn't test yet on my nexus. Have you tried the emulator?

Comment: I have the same issue on a Nexus 5 (whether or not "allowBackup="true" is present) with latest dev preview

Comment: I've also run into this.

Comment: I followed up with the bug tracker and the issue is fixed. Could you answer this question with this fact ? (just to complete the process)

Comment: :( Fixed the problem by rebooting the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in the final release of Android 6.0, as per the official issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2965

Comment: I am using CM13.0 Android 6.0.1 on a Nexus 4 and the problem is still there.